# How to fix the screen being to bright in Ubuntu 12.04 and up

Tags: unity, bash, scripts, screen, brightness

How to fix the screen brightness and color being too bright in ubuntu.

Comment: Please read http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution to a problem i have had with Ubuntu for a while, For some reason on my laptop the screen colors are way to bright, Whites are almost blinding white, So i made this little bash script to fix it automatically.

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1m
exec xrandr --output LVDS1 --gamma 0.8:0.8:0.8 --brightness 0.9
exit 0
```

Then to make it run on startup, Type in "startup" into the unity dash and go to startup applications, Then add the script and it will run on startup fixing this problem automatically.

But first you may need to make the script executable by doing:

```
sudo chmod +x screenfix.sh
```

Reboot and after 1 minute the screen should look much better, Tweak the xrandr command in the bash script to suit your needs.

In addition to this solution you can also fix the problem with the screen being completely black or too dark on boot with the command below.

```
sudo sed "s/\(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\)\"\"/\1\"acpi_­osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor\"/" /etc/default/grub -i
```

And then do:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot.